# query causing huge cpu utilization on my database

Tags: mysql

following query is causing high cpu utilization on db is there any help to re write this query to improve the performance of this query.

```
SELECT 
    de.infgrdt, 
    de.hfg, 
    de.dfg, 
    de.hjr, 
    e.ufl as exchange, 
    de.efxd, 
    t.jdnm AS prkr 
FROM mnvb.hjvgf de
JOIN mnvb.yefg e ON (de.efxd = e.fgd)
JOIN mnvb.fjtn t ON (de.gefvb = t.fgd)
WHERE de.infgrdt >= '2022-10-14 00:04:20.000000' AND de.infgrdt < '2022-10-14 03:22:54.000000';
```

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the columns used in the `ON` clauses and the `de.infgrdt` column.

Comment: Other than that, there's probably nothing that can be done to improve it.

Comment: yes i have index on de.infgrdt its a timestamp colunm

Comment: Can you post the result for `EXPLAIN` to this query?

Comment: Explain, and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for these 3 tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These may help some:

```
de:  INDEX(infgrdt)  -- you already have this
e:  INDEX(fgd,  ufl)
t:  INDEX(fgd,  jdnm)
```

The last two are "covering", which gives a slight performance boost.

For further investigation, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE ...
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```